# Setting up reverse proxy to forward requests to the backend server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, nginx

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy using nginx.

Spring boot app runs at http://10.0.0.6:8080/petclinic and the nginx is exposed at 20.56.91.154, but they are in the same private network. I've used provided below nginx.conf, but requests sent to backend are not working, only static files are loaded. Can anyone help?

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html;
  location /petclinic/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/petclinic/dist/;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /petclinic/index.html;
  }
  location /petclinic/api/ {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.6:8080/petclinic/api;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```